# Storing user created folders in SQL database

Tags: sql, database

I am a high school student building an app for students in my school to store their grades and help with their organisation overall. In this app the users can create folders and add grades to these folders. I am using a SQL database for storing the grades. My database currently looks something like this:

I have two tables to store the information, the first one is for the subjects like this:

| UserID | ID | DisplayName | ParentID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| abcd | 1 | English | null |
| defg | 2 | Vocabulary | 1 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |

Note that the `ParentID` is either the `ID` of another folder to create nested folders, or null.

A table for the grades:

| UserID | ID | FolderID | Grade | DisplayName |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| abcd | 1 | 1 | A | Grammar Test |
| defg | 2 | 2 | B | Vocabulary pages 12-13 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |

Here the `FolderID` refers to a folder from the table above.

As well as a table for the users:

| UserID | FirstName | LastName | Email | Password |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| abcd | Alice | Smith | alice.smith@example.com | $$ |
| defg | Bob | Brown | bob.brown@example.com | $$ |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |

Upon creating an account the user can decide to either chose a configuration template or skip this step. When he chooses a template he is prompted to choose his subjects from a few options (for example you can choose the second language between German and Italian). And these folders then get created and added to the database.

I now want to store the choices the user made to do some data analysis with it. The problem is that I want the user to be able to edit the folder name if he wants to... A nice bonus would be if I could translate the folders using i18n.

I have thought about creating a new table with all possible subjects, each getting a new id which is a prime number so I can multiply them to store the users unique configuration as well as creating a new column in the table for the `SubjectID` in the tables and query all the folders from a user. Would this be a good idea?

Do you have any other suggestions for me? (this is my first project of this size and I am happy for all feedback)

Comment: Are the folders also folders in the filesystem?

Comment: No they are not, we started the project as a web app but switched to react native to be able to scan the tests using native capabilities

Comment: Well, in that case, I would create a table that would contain the folders along with their default names. I would also create a new table that would store display name modifications for folders of users. The second table would be a many-to-many relation between users and folders. The only thing preventing me from answering your question is the i18n part, which was unclear to me. Can you elaborate on that?

Comment: So for the translations I use i18n, every subject has an unique string in a json file, for example English would be subjects.english, Maths is subjects.math etc...

Answer (score 0):

I would change the approach. I would have a table for subjects of the format of:

**subjects(id, parentID, displayName)**

and there would be a many-to-many relation for subject-user, like

**user_subjects(id, userID, subjectID, displayName)**

that would represent that a user is learning a given subject. Finally, I would create a custom_subjects table of the format of

**custom_subjects(id, subjectID, userID, displayName)**

so, if a user has a custom `displayName`, then that would be used and the value would fall back to the `user_subjects`'s `displayName`, a common pattern in queries would be the following:

```
SELECT COALESCE(custom_subjects.displayName, subjects.displayName)
FROM users
JOIN user_subjects
on users.id = user_subjects.userID
JOIN subjects
on user_subjects.subjectID = subjects.id
LEFT JOIN custom_subjects
ON subjects.id = custom_subjects.subjectID AND users.id = custom_subjects.userID
```

This way you will have a default to fall back to and you could override it for each user. I'm unsure about your intention about i18n, you have provided some information about that, but not enough for me to include ideas about it into my answer.